# Use use_framework! in Podfile which have both Swift & Objective C/C Pod

Tags: cocoapods, xcode8, cocoapods-1.1.1

I know use_framework! is used for swift libraries but what to do if want to use Obj-C and Swift libraries in one project

Is there any method to use

`use_framework!` for seperate pods

Answer (score 0):

With cocoa pods 1.1.1 you can now have use_frameworks! inside one or more targets in your Podfile. This allows you to use frameworks for some targets and not for others!

Comment: Yes @ericWasTaken you are right but i am using only one Target where some pods are Swift and some are Objective C. Among Objective C pods some are compiled and some are not. For example you can try on your Xcode for Alamofire and RestComm Mobile - iOS SDK in one project

Comment: @UsamaSadiq, I see what you mean. There are multiple bugs that speak to this, including https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4605.

Comment: @UsamaSadiq, BTW, I don't know if this is a feasible alternative for you. But, AlamoFire actually is the "swift" rewrite of AFNetworking. Since mixing Swift and Objc-C is proving difficult, perhaps try AFNetworking. I just tested `pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'` instead of AlamoFire and commented out use_frameworks! - and that builds correctly as we'd expect. I realize this might not be the best alternative for you, though.